# Does Z3 solver internally unnests nested function terms

Tags: z3

I was wondering if the Z3 solver (perhaps only in some circumstances) uses a graph of a function to unnest a nested function term by introducing a new quantified variable.

For example: `f(g(5)) = 10` could be expressed as: `∀ x : x = g(5)⇒f(x) = 10` or with the graph `Gg` of `g` : `∀ x : Gg(5,x)⇒f(x) = 10`

If something like this is happening, I wanted to ask if anyone could point me to the relevant reference.

I tried quickly to find the answer in the documentation provided by Z3 and in publications but without success.

Answer (score 1):

If `f`/`g` etc. are defined functions, they'll be expanded. If they're uninterpreted symbols, then what you're describing seems to be similar to Ackermann's reduction, which is used to remove uninterpreted functions. (Which can, of course, appear in nested positions.)

- For each application f(a1, a2, ...) in φ create a fresh variable f_a1_a2...
- For each pair of applications f(a1, a2, ...), f(b1, b2, ...) in φ add the formula a1 = b1 /\ a2 = b2 ... /\ an = bn -> f_a1_a2... = f_b1_b2...

There's a bunch of slides on the internet that mention this technique, see https://www.logic.at/lvas/fminf/11S/folien/e/fminf_sat4.pdf for an example.